# Using K-NN Algorithm with more than two attributes

Tags: statistics, algorithms

If I were to have dataset of 9 attributes of different types that describe current weather, such as temperature, humidity etc. and want to classify the current weather by use of a K-NN algorithm, is this possible?

From what I understand, K-NN has two different attributes that are plotted and wherever a point is drawn, its nearest neighbors will classify it.

Could I do the same thing but each data point is placed based on its 9 attributes?

Comment: This is the wrong site to post this. ai.stackexchange is the most suitable for this question (there is a kNN tag).

Comment: @ThePointer also stats.stackexchange and datascience.stackexchange which each have that tag (or equivalent)

Comment: $k$-nearest neighbours is a technique based on distance, so you can certainly do this in more than two dimensions so long as you a have a sensible measure of distance between points (such as rescaling)

Comment: @Henry I would say yes, *but* this type of question is more of a high-level machine learning question, rather than a statistics-based machine learning question, and so I would say that it's more suited for ai.stackexchange rather than stats.stackexchange. I think datascience.stackexchange is more-so about professional data science (kind of like softwareengineering.stackexchange vs stackoverflow).

Comment: @Henry I'm new to machine learning, so forgive me if I'm misunderstanding. From my beliefs, there can only be 3 dimensional space and K-NN calculates the distance between these points, how would it be possible to measure distance between points that have 9 dimensions?

Comment: @ThePointer  [ai.stackexchange has 4 questions tagged k-nearest-neighbors](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-nearest-neighbors) while  [stats.stackexchange has 472](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-nearest-neighbour) and [datascience.stackexchange has 132](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-nn)

Comment: @Infrared I suggest you copy and paste this question to ai.stackexchange and delete this one. And if you have a question about the statistics involved in kNN, then I suggest you ask over at stats.stackexchange.

Comment: @Henry Point taken.